# Airflow DataProcPySparkOperator not considering cluster other than global region

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am performing some operation using `DataProcPySparkOperator`. This operator is only taking a cluster name as parameter, there is no option to specify region and by default it considers cluster with global region.
For clusters with regions other than global, the following error occurs:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects//regions/global/jobs:submit?alt=json returned "No current cluster for project id '' with name ''`

Am i missing anything or its just limitation with these operators?

Answer (score 3):

These DataProc{PySpark|Spark|Hive|Hadoop|..}Operators simply don't support region argument today, an airflow [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1576) has been created and I'll submit a fix in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know , Please update me once this issue gets fixed .

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2625) submitted to Airflow, should be merged in a few days.

Comment: What is the latest status of this? Still running into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry just saw it's been updated. I was using Airflow through GCP. They haven't updated it yet.

Answer (score 1):

We were running into the same issue using Google Composer, which was running Airflow 1.9.  We upgrade to Airflow 1.10 and this fixed the issue.  Google just released it.  Now, when I run the operator it can see the cluster - it looks in the correct region.  Previously it was always looking in global.